# Raspberry Pi Server in Inittab

Tags: linux, unix, raspberry-pi

On my raspberry pi, I want my own written server to be started at startup, and to be restarted when it segfaults, so I added it to `/etc/inittab`. The problem is that the server won't start

The line I added:

```
1:2345:respawn:/home/gear/lionfish/main /home/gear/lionfish/app
```

When I run this command from the command line it works just fine, but the server doesn't run. I've checked this with `ps aux`, and it didn't show up

Have I made some sort of mistake?

EDIT: Small side question. The server needs root privileges, does inittab do this automatically or do I need to add something to it?

Comment: Executables/scripts started from inittab probably do not have the same environment settings as when you start them from a regular login shell. Is there anything in your scripts that might depend on them?

Answer (score 0):

Typical problems:

1. As already mentioned, environment is set up differently. Make sure $PATH iscorrect.
2. Does your program try to execute in a directory which becomes unmounted? If so, cd to / first.
3. Access restrictions to files and directories.
4. Process doesn't detach from stdin/stdout/stderr.
5. The process runs in foreground instead of background.
6. Parent process receives a terminating signal such as SIGTERM which kills your process as well. Try ignoring this (and some others) signals by using nohup or sigset/sigignore.

Debugging hint: Let the server start by appending current time to the end of an already existing file in a directory which is guaranteed to be writable. Make sure you flush (and close) the file pointer immediately. Then at least you can see whether it was started at all or not.